# Determine if Record is New Record

Tags: apex, class

I am trying to insert a condition to check if a record is a new record vs. an existing record in a trigger, but I'm not sure how to incorporate it in my condition?  I'm sure it's fairly simple, I'm just not sure how.

```
if(opp.Account.Type != null && opp.Account.Type.equals('Test') && opp.Advertiser__c == null)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Trigger Context Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) to determine your current state:

```
if(Trigger.isInsert && opp.Account.Type != null ...
```